# Access attribute outside of the current binding context in knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Here I want to print the value of the user name in the top of the list,List values display as I expected, but username does not show, http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/16/
Html

```
   <div data-role="page" id="dashBoardPage" data-bind="with: dashboardData">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: goToList">DashBoard!</button>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="firstPage" data-bind="with: dashboardData.hospitalList">
    <div>
        <h4>User Name <span data-bind="text:$root.dashboardData.userName"></span></h4>
        <div id="listViewDiv">
             <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="foreach: hospitals">
                <li data-bind="click:$root.selectHospital">
                    <h2>Hospital Id:<span data-bind="text:id"></span></h2>
                    <p>Name <span data-bind="text:name"></span></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div data-role="page" id="detailsView" data-bind="with: dashboardData.hospitalList.selectedHospital">
    <a href="#firstPage">Back</a>
    <a href="#dashBoardPage">Home</a>
    <div>
        <h2>Hospital Id : <span data-bind="text:id"></span></h2>
        <input data-mini="true" tabindex="5" data-bind="value: name"
               id="name"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

objects

```
function NavigationService(){
    var self = this;

    self.navigateTo = function(pageId){
        $.mobile.changePage($('#' + pageId));
    };
}

var navigationService = new NavigationService();

function HospitalViewModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.id;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

function DashboardViewModel(parentView){
    var self = this;
    self.userName = ko.observable("Ude"); 
    self.hospitalList = ko.observable();
    //This list should be retrieved from a service of some kind
    var allHospitals = [
        {"id":"001","name":"Hospital1","location":"SL"},
        {"id":"002","name":"Hospital2","location":"SL"}
    ].map(function(hospital){return new HospitalViewModel(hospital);});


    self.goToList = function(){
        self.hospitalList(new HospitalListViewModel(allHospitals));
        navigationService.navigateTo('firstPage');
    };
}

    function HospitalListViewModel(data){
        var self = this;

        self.hospitals = data;
        self.selectedHospital = ko.observable();

        self.selectHospital = function(hospital){
            self.selectedHospital(hospital);
            navigationService.navigateTo('detailsView');
        };
    }

    function PageViewModel(){
        var self = this;
        self.dashboardData = new DashboardViewModel(self);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
```

I want to implement my listview in DashboardViewModel,There are two problems need to address
userName does not show in UI, Couldn't load detail page, can anyone help me to solve this

Thank you,

Comment: Your fiddle fails with `hospitalList is not defined`

Comment: Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Hpyca/17/

Comment: @ Ex: To improve the question, use the "edit" link under the question.

Comment: updated with all code, When user click list element it goes to details page,currently it does not go to detail page

Comment: @ Ex: You've updated the question so that it *incorporates* my answer. That's not how SO works. You leave the problem in the question, and accept the answer that solves it. If you have a *further* problem, you ask a new question.

Comment: Here I have two problems,I asked those in my question, you answered on of them, I tried to solve my second problem based on your answer, but I still couldn't figure it out,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50806/discussion-between-excode-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the second. But in any case, it's important not to update the question to incorporate answers. The point of SO isn't just to help you now, it's to help others later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
<h4>User Name<span data-bind="text:$root.dashboardData.userName"></span></h4>
```

or alternately

```
<h4>User Name<span data-bind="text:$parent.dashboardData.userName"></span></h4>
```

Given that `userName` and `hospitalList` are peers in your `DashboardViewModel`, and you're referencing `hospitalList` as `dashboardData.hospitalList`, that tells me that your root view model has an instance of `DashboardViewModel` on it as `dashboardData`. So assuming that you're bound to the root view model at the beginning of your quoted HTML, as you're using `dashboardData.hospitalList` to get at the list, I assume it would be `dashboardData.userName` to get at the username (from the root). So, `$root.dashboardData.userName`. Or since we know `dashboardData` is a child of the parent context, `$parent.dashboardData.userName`.

Comment: Thank you, userName is now working, but still couldn't access detail page  <li data-bind="click: $parent.selectHospital">, how can I load detail page in this way

Comment: @ExCode: Where do you mean? (Also, quote **all** of the code that's in the fiddle in the question itself.)